# In sequelize, how do I select records that match all values that i am searching for?

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

As an example, I have the following table:

```
T | S
------
1 | 5
1 | 6
1 | 7
2 | 6
2 | 7
3 | 6
```

Query: array [1,2]

I want to select all values in S that have the value 1 AND 2 in the T Column.

So in the above example I should get as a result (6,7) because only 6 and 7 have for column T the values 1 and 2.

But i do not want to have 5 in my results as 5 does not have 2 in the T column.
How would I do this in sequelize?

Comment: "_I should get as a result (5,6) because only 5 and 6 have for column T the values 1 and 2_" Where? .. I only see 6 having both 1 and 2 from T..

Comment: sorry 6 & 7. Edited.

Comment: @Alpaca . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do i make (1,2) to be used as an array?

Either you insert the array joined  as comma-separated literal into the query text (variant 1) or you join the array into one string literal and transfer it iinto the query as a parameter (variant 2).

Variant 1

```
SELECT s
FROM sourcetable
WHERE t IN (1,2)              -- separate filter values
GROUP BY s
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t) = 2  -- unique values count
```

Variant 2

```
SELECT s
FROM sourcetable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t, '1,2')   -- separate filter values
GROUP BY s
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t) = 2  -- unique values count
```

If `(s,t)` is unique then DISTINCT keyword may be removed.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in sequelize? and how do i make (1,2) to be used as an array?

Comment: @Alpaca Fast searching shows that sequelize allows [raw SQL](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/raw-queries.html). And no mention about grouping...

Comment: @Alpaca *how do i make (1,2) to be used as an array?* Updated.